# How to handle correctly the views

Tags: ios, swift, view, controller, navigation

I've a problem because of my views inside a Navigation Controller. Picture 1 describes my main view. If I click something in the main view, it should push to ViewController B. That happen but the new UI looks like Picture 2. But I want the UI looks like Picture 3 - that means ViewController C and ViewController D should be disabled. And if I go back from ViewController B it should looks like Picture 1 again.

I know the picture is a little bit confusing but I hope you guys understand my problem.

Could you please help me?[image]

Comment: what did you tried ? and add come code.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I come with question but

- ViewController C, D are children of which ViewController? NavigationController or ViewController A?

from your illustration and current situation, look like C,D are children of NavigationController but may not be `UINaviationController.viewControllers`?

So if that's the case, your have to add C,D as children of A, then when you push B from A, it should become picture 3.